# Drawing a square line with CSS, inset within a div

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it were possible to trace a 1px square outline, inset a specific distance inside a div. Currently, the css and HTML looks like this

```css
.object {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

Resulting in this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEEvA.png

And the intended result would be like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Wu7.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method #01:**

You can draw `outline` and use `outline-offset` property.

> **Note:** `outline-offset` is not supported by IE.

```css
.object {
  outline: solid #fff 1px;
  outline-offset: -5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

**Method #02:**

You can use `:before` or `:after` pseudo element to draw the outline OR the `background` extending from all sides.

```css
.object {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.object:before {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

**Method # 03:**

You can draw multiple background images using css3 [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient). Below is the necessary css:

```
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, white),
                    linear-gradient(to bottom, white, white),
                    linear-gradient(to right, white, white),
                    linear-gradient(to bottom, white, white),
                    linear-gradient(to right, red, red);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: calc(100% - 10px) 1px, 1px calc(100% - 10px), calc(100% - 10px) 1px, 1px calc(100% - 10px), 100% 100%;
  background-position:  5px 5px, top 5px right 5px, bottom 5px right 5px, 5px 5px, 0 0;
}
```

```css
.object {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, white),
                      linear-gradient(to bottom, white, white),
                      linear-gradient(to right, white, white),
                      linear-gradient(to bottom, white, white),
                      linear-gradient(to right, red, red);
    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: calc(100% - 10px) 1px, 1px calc(100% - 10px), calc(100% - 10px) 1px, 1px calc(100% - 10px), 100% 100%;
    background-position:  5px 5px, top 5px right 5px, bottom 5px right 5px, 5px 5px, 0 0;
    
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

Comment: Beaut, I knew there had to be a css attribute, I was googling for "inset" and "outset", but didn't think about trying to find "offset".

Answer (score 2):

You can play with `box-shadow` attribute:

```css
.object {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good solution too, simple like outline-offset, and it'd work with IE. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it

```
.object {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.object::after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 97.5px;
    height: 97.5px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `border` property and set a `margin` (because `margin` is outside the border).  If you don't want the total size of the div to change, reduce `padding` to compensate for the margin.

Answer (score 0):

Also possible with two box-shadows:

```css
.object {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px red, inset 0 0 0 5px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by adding a span inside div or write a jquery script to add it automatically.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .object, .object-js {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;   
        position: relative;
    }
    .object span, .object-js span{
        border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        padding: 2px;
        height: calc(100% - 5px);
        display: block;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="object">
   <span>Hello World.</span> 
</div>
 <br>
<div class="object-js">
   Hello World.
</div>
</body>
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      var html = $(".object-js").html();
      $(".object-js").html("<span>"+html+"</span>");
    });
    </script>
</html>
```